# C# Day of the year

Tags: c#, datetime

The objective:

> Enter 3 positve numbers that present the day, month and year of a 
>   date. The day number then needs to be showed. For example: the day number for 1975/12/31 is 365.

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //declaration of variables
        int day, month, year;

        //user input
        Console.Write("Day: ");
        day = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Month: ");
        month = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Year: ");
        year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //creating an object named date of type datetime
        DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);

        //output the day number
        Console.WriteLine("Day number: " +date.DayOfYear);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a superfluous `}` at the end of your post. Also, is this from a programming challenge website?

Comment: @Zeta it was from a practice bundle from college. The post is corrected.

Comment: Change not corrected

Comment: I would extract a method that get a `DateTime` and returns the *dayOfYear* of it as an  `int`. Do not mix up input output and the computation all in one method.

Answer (score 2):

## Validation

Nowhere in your code do you validate the input of the user. If I enter some random text you'll get a `FormatException` with following message:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Before processing input, check if it is in the correct format. In this case you can use the [**Int32.TryParse Method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int inputAsInt;

if (int.TryParse(input, out inputAsInt))
{
    //process the correct input
}
else
{
    //ask for correct input
}
```

### Asking for input

Now that we have valiadtion on the input, we need to keep asking the user until the input is correct. We need a loop-mechanism for this: the `do-while` is very useful here:

```
do
{
    //provide a message
    //ask for input
}
while (//input not correct);
```

Real code:

```
int output;
bool isInputCorrect;

do
{
    Console.Write(message);
    isInputCorrect = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out output);

    if (!isInputCorrect)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input must be numeric, please try again...");
    }
} while (!isInputCorrect);
```

This will keep asking for input until it is correct.

### Using a method

In your case, you need to ask for 3 numbers, so you won't repeat that same block of code 3 times. Throw it in a method and reuse it whenever you need it:

```
public static int GetNumericInput(string message)
{
    int output;
    bool isInputCorrect;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(message);
        isInputCorrect = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out output);

        if (!isInputCorrect)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input must be numeric, please try again...");
        }
    } while (!isInputCorrect);

    return output;
}
```

And a sample usage:

```
int day = GetNumericInput("Day: ");
```

### Extra

1. You can add extra validation to check if the number is valid. A month ranges from 1-12 and days from 1-31, so you could/should check on that too.
2. Use the [**var**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var) keyword if you know the type already:

> The var keyword can also be useful when the specific type of the variable is tedious to type on the keyboard, or is obvious, or does not add to the readability of the code.